# shift columns of first row in csv in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file in which first row is having column names. I want to shuffle only column names excluding 1st column of fist row(A1).

My CSV looks like:

```
"name","A","B","C","D"  
"Romi", 5,  6,  3,  6  
"Meli", 5,  8,  9,  7  
"John", 3,  6,  8,  9
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
"name","C","A","D","B"  
"Romi", 5,  6,  3,  6  
"Meli", 5,  8,  9,  7  
"John", 3,  6,  8,  9
```

This is my code:

```
infile = open('data.csv', 'r')

table = []

for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ','):
    table.append(row)
infile.close()


table_one = ' '.join(table[0])
table_one = table_one.split(' ')
table_one = table_one[1:10]
for i in range(1,11):
    random.shuffle(table_one)
    table[0] = table_one
    print table[0]
```

It is printing it like this:

```
"C","A","D","B"  
"Romi", 5,  6,  3,  6  
"Meli", 5,  8,  9,  7  
"John", 3,  6,  8,  9
```

I'm using python 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i have solved it

```
table_one = table[0][2:]
for i in range(1,11):  
    random.shuffle(table_one)
    table[0][2:] = table_one
    print table[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 
infile = open('S228c_foldvalues_modified.csv', 'r')

table = []

for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ','):
    table.append(row)
infile.close()


table_one = table[0]
table_one[1], table_one[2], table_one[3], table_one[4] = 
table_one[3], table_one[1], table_one[4], table_one[2]
table[0] = table_one

print(table)

with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(table)
```

Just swap the first row items in the list and write back to the file.Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought the question was about shuffling, not swapping and more over its no where mentioned that he has only four columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
table = []
with open('S228c_foldvalues_modified.csv', 'r') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ','):
        table.append(row)

table_one = table[0][1:]
random.shuffle(table_one)
table_one = [table[0][0]]+table_one
print (table_one)
```

Comment: Thank you Amey. But this does not work in a loop. It prints "names" twice in next loop and so on........

Comment: why do you need to keep it in loop ? In your code you are shuffling the same array `table_one` 10 times and overwriting it each time in `table[0]`. Hence I removed the loop